# vim character not showing up correctly in Windows 7

Tags: vim

I having trouble with some characters in Vim not showing up correctly.
I have bare bones Vim in Windows 7.
For example
► shows up as ?   and

Ξ shows up as ?

I think it has to do with encoding. the current encoding is latin1
Any suggestions to resolve the issue ?

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking a minimal, complete, verifiable example makes it hard to answer.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Answer (score 0):

To change the encoding, edit the **.vimrc** or in Vim *last line mode*

`:set encoding=utf-8`

A easy way to echo the location of the vimrc file in Vim

`:echo $MYVIMRC`

Good luck